# Regex - How to properly grab nested value

Tags: regex

I understand parsing html with a regex isn't ideal, but I have a use case for it.

I have this coverage report/html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>LCOV - .info.cleaned</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gcov.css">
</head>

<body>

  <table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr><td class="title">LCOV - code coverage report</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="ruler"><img src="glass.png" width=3 height=3 alt=""></td></tr>

    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <table cellpadding=1 border=0 width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="10%" class="headerItem">Current view:</td>
            <td width="35%" class="headerValue">top level</td>
            <td width="5%"></td>
            <td width="15%"></td>
            <td width="10%" class="headerCovTableHead">Hit</td>
            <td width="10%" class="headerCovTableHead">Total</td>
            <td width="15%" class="headerCovTableHead">Coverage</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headerItem">Test:</td>
            <td class="headerValue">.info.cleaned</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="headerItem">Lines:</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntry">399</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntry">1019</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">39.2 %</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="headerItem">Date:</td>
            <td class="headerValue">2016-11-07</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="headerItem">Functions:</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntry">22</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntry">67</td>
            <td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">32.8 %</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td><img src="glass.png" width=3 height=3 alt=""></td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td class="ruler"><img src="glass.png" width=3 height=3 alt=""></td></tr>
  </table>

  <center>
  <table width="80%" cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=0>

    <tr>
      <td width="50%"><br></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
      <td width="10%"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="tableHead">Directory <span class="tableHeadSort"><img src="glass.png" width=10 height=14 alt="Sort by name" title="Sort by name" border=0></span></td>
      <td class="tableHead" colspan=3>Line Coverage <span class="tableHeadSort"><a href="index-sort-l.html"><img src="updown.png" width=10 height=14 alt="Sort by line coverage" title="Sort by line coverage" border=0></a></span></td>
      <td class="tableHead" colspan=2>Functions <span class="tableHeadSort"><a href="index-sort-f.html"><img src="updown.png" width=10 height=14 alt="Sort by function coverage" title="Sort by function coverage" border=0></a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="coverFile"><a href="src/index.html">src</a></td>
      <td class="coverBar" align="center">
        <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1><tr><td class="coverBarOutline"><img src="ruby.png" width=39 height=10 alt="39.2%"><img src="snow.png" width=61 height=10 alt="39.2%"></td></tr></table>
      </td>
      <td class="coverPerLo">39.2&nbsp;%</td>
      <td class="coverNumLo">399 / 1019</td>
      <td class="coverPerLo">32.8&nbsp;%</td>
      <td class="coverNumLo">22 / 67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </center>
  <br>

  <table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr><td class="ruler"><img src="glass.png" width=3 height=3 alt=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="versionInfo">Generated by: <a href="http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php">LCOV version 1.10</a></td></tr>
  </table>
  <br>

</body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to parse out the data from this line:

```
    <td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">39.2 %</td>
```

as 39.2 (a float value).

I am currently using this regex to find two matching TD's:

```
<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">[0-9.].*?.%<\/td>
```

I'm misunderstanding how groups work.  I tried:

```
(<td class="headerCovTableEntryLo">[0-9.].*?.%<\/td>)[0-9.].*?\1
```

To take what was found in the first group and grab just the numberical values but I have zero matches.  Can anyone lend some insight into what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: `Regex - How to properly grab nested value?` ... don't use regex, use an HTML parser.

Comment: Thank you both...I understand HTML parser would be preferred, and I am in rails.  Unfortunately this is not easily achieved with the system/context I am working in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to perform? (capture only the floating value):

`<(td) class="headerCovTableEntryLo">([0-9.]+)\s?%<\/\1>`

see it working here: https://regex101.com/r/qprROm/2

If so, if you try to reuse the first match you're making correct use of it with `\1` or to etc to match which captured group. but in your trial you also captured the class which wont match in closing tag.

Not sure this is really what you try to do though. haha

Plus, in this case doing `<(td)>(.*?)<\/\1>` does not really make sense. It is more usefill if your usecase is something like this `<(td|th|tr)>(.*?)<\/\1>`

In the end if I was doing it I would rather do it this way for more flexibility: `(?<=class="headerCovTableEntryLo">)([0-9.]+)(?=\s?%)`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/qprROm/3

Comment: Thank you!  (?<=class="headerCovTableEntryLo">)([0-9.]+)(?=\s?%)  was exactly what I needed to capture the floating value